# SonarQube Eclipse plugin 3.4 Sonar server can not be reached because of connection time out

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, static-code-analysis

I've installed SonarQube Eclipse plugin 3.4 on RAD 9 (Eclipse 4.2 )
I have provided the server URL (SonarQube server 4.5.4) and tested the connection... Everything is OK.

When I've associated my project to SonarQube the project is recognised but when it starts to retrieve remote issue (after click on analyse) I get this exception:

```
Retrieve remote issues of project myProject...
Start SonarQube analysis on myProject...
ERROR: Sonar server 'https://sonarServer/sonar' can not be reached
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1392)
    at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.ok(HttpRequest.java:1417)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:90)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.downloadVersion(ServerVersion.java:48)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.version(ServerVersion.java:39)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.is35Compatible(ServerVersion.java:63)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:39)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:71)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:274)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:529)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1674)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1672)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:330)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1670)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1243)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getResponseCode(b.java:27)
    at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1390)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:358)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:219)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:201)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.connect(qc.java:46)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:395)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:490)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.<init>(c.java:179)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.a(c.java:172)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.getNewHttpClient(d.java:21)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:62)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2677)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getHeaderField(b.java:35)
    at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.header(HttpRequest.java:1903)
    at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.contentType(HttpRequest.java:2308)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:86)
    ... 10 more
```

**edit**
here is server access.log

```
     127.0.0.1 - - [03/01/2016:10:26:58 +0200] "GET /sonar/api/server/index HTTP/1.1" 200 55 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.2.2 (java 1.5)"
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/01/2016:10:27:05 +0200] "GET /sonar/api/authentication/validate HTTP/1.1" 200 14 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.2.2 (java 1.5)"
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/01/2016:10:27:16 +0200] "GET /sonar/api/server/index HTTP/1.1" 200 55 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.2.2 (java 1.5)"
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/01/2016:10:27:55 +0200] "GET /sonar/api/resources?resource=com.myproject%3Amymodule%3ASNAPSHOT&verbose=false& HTTP/1.1" 200 306 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.2.2 (java 1.5)"
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/01/2016:10:28:04 +0200] "GET /sonar/api/issues/search?resolved=false&pageSize=-1&componentRoots=com.myproject:mymodule:SNAPSHOT&pageIndex=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Java/1.7.0"
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/01/2016:10:28:09 +0200] "GET /sonar/api/issues/search?resolved=false&pageSize=-1&componentRoots=com.myproject:mymodule:SNAPSHOT&pageIndex=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Java/1.7.0"
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/01/2016:10:28:13 +0200] "GET /sonar/api/issues/search?resolved=false&pageSize=-1&componentRoots=com.myproject:mymodule:SNAPSHOT&pageIndex=3 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Java/1.7.0"
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/01/2016:10:28:17 +0200] "GET /sonar/api/issues/search?resolved=false&pageSize=-1&componentRoots=com.myproject:mymodule:SNAPSHOT&pageIndex=4 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Java/1.7.0"
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/01/2016:10:28:21 +0200] "GET /sonar/api/issues/search?resolved=false&pageSize=-1&componentRoots=com.myproject:mymodule:SNAPSHOT&pageIndex=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Java/1.7.0"
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/01/2016:10:28:24 +0200] "GET /sonar/api/issues/search?resolved=false&pageSize=-1&componentRoots=com.myproject:mymodule:SNAPSHOT&pageIndex=6 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Java/1.7.0"
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/01/2016:10:28:36 +0200] "GET /sonar/api/resources?resource=com.myproject%3Amymodule%3ASNAPSHOT&metrics=&verbose=false& HTTP/1.1" 200 306 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.2.2 (java 1.5)"
```

Nothing is displayed on the sonar.log file

**end of edit**

Sometimes it retrieve a part of the issue sometimes no one of them

Thanks

Comment: This looks like an issue on server side. Can you check server logs? Can you monitor server health (CPU, I/O) when the timeout occurs?

Comment: I've tried to connect to two different servers and I got the same issue. I don't have access to them I will use another one where I can access and keep you informed

Comment: With the new server the blugin works fine although I cannot see all the issues, it presents a max of 100 per criticity. in the other hand I'm waiting for the other servers traces to check them.

Comment: can you go with http (not https, i.e. without security) .. I m thinking if there might be problem with the cert, and you might need to import the cert to java before establish the connection in RAD.

Comment: I don't think it's a certificate matter because the project is retrieved on the server when i link it from RAD, also i can get some issue (not all of them) although i have the time out error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the following command is executed when launching analyse using eclipse:

```
java.exe -cp C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\sonar-runner-impl6867841822221012221.jar 
org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain 
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\sonar-project3666940761827968492.properties
```

Because I'am working behind a proxy which is configurated in eclipse network preferences section, it will not reach the server unless the proxy configuration is added.
So to test I have executed the command line with the proxy configuration options for https (-Dhttps.proxyHost -Dhttps.proxyPort -Dhttps.proxyUser -Dhttps.proxyPassword) and the command have succeeded.

I think it's a bug. The plugin must check either a proxy configuration exists or not before creating and launching the command

**Edit**

To resolve the problem go to preferences>>SonarQube>>JVM arguments for preview analysis: put the proxy params in that field and it should works

Comment: Have the same issue, but I cannot find: preferences>>SonarQube.

Comment: Must have it if you install SonarQube eclipse plugin.